# Having trouble with php array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to only output unique urls with the following code:

```
$i = 0;             
while ( loop ) {                            
  $unique[i] = $field['link'];
  if(in_array($field['link'],$unique[])){
      do something                              
      i++;
  } else {
      do something else
      i++;
  }
}
```

However I'm getting an error saying Cannot use [] for reading in on line 71 which is:

```
if(in_array($field['link'],$unique[])){
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Comment: What does the syntax `$unique[]` mean to you in this case? What are you using if for?

Comment: i wanted to put each string into the $unique[] array, and then use that to decide what to do next, my logic could be complete flawed, if you can recomend a better way please do so.

Comment: @Kal But `$field['link']` is always the same string inside this loop. Are you sure you want to and `n` times this string in the array `$unique`?

Comment: no, i want the $unique array to have a new value added to it every time.  ive confused myself with this, its hard to explain

Answer (score 5):

`in_array` takes as a second parameter an array. So use just `$unique`.

`$unique[]` syntax can be used only for pushing elements into this array.

Answer (score 2):

If $unique is an array so you need to write

```
if(in_array($field['link'],$unique)){
```

instead of

```
if(in_array($field['link'],$unique[])){
```

But in din't understand the logic of the code :

You put `$field['link']` in the index `i` of your array, so this value is always in `$unique` and `in_array()` will always return `true`

Answer (score 1):

It is because in `$unique[]`, the `[]` indicates the next position to write to in array, you can't use it for reading an array. You need to specify the index of $unique into `[]`, like  `[$i]`, or remove them to point at the full array

Comment: hsz made the point, I didn't see it was inside in_array. Just noted a non-left-side was at the left side!